# Find the maximum value of $x(9\sqrt{1+x^2}​+13\sqrt{1-x^2​})​$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $0\le x \le 1$
find the maximum value of $x(9\sqrt{1+x^2}​+13\sqrt{1-x^2​})​$

I try to use am-gm inequality to solve this because it's similar to CMIMC2020 team prob.12 but i don't know how to do next.

Comment: Have you tried a calculus approach?

Comment: Yeah, calculus will yield to this maximum value: 16.

Answer (score 5):

Even though I still believe that the calculus approach is the most suited for the problem, consider the somehow *magical* ansatz I found: \begin{align*}x\cdot\left(9\sqrt{1+x^2}​+13\sqrt{1-x^2​}\right)​&=2\cdot \frac34\cdot 3x\cdot 2\cdot \sqrt{1+x^2}+2\cdot\frac{13}4\cdot x\cdot2\sqrt{1-x^2}\\&\stackrel{AM-GM}{\leqslant}\frac34\cdot\left(9x^2+4\cdot(1+x^2)\right)+\frac{13}4\cdot \left(x^2+4\cdot (1-x^2)\right)\\&=16\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$x\left(9\sqrt{1+x^2}​+13\sqrt{1-x^2​}\right)\leq x\sqrt{(27+13)(3(1+x^2)+13(1-x^2))}=​$$
$$=\sqrt{16\cdot5x^2(8-5x^2)}\leq\sqrt{16\left(\frac{5x^2+8-5x^2}{2}\right)^2}=16.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt5},$ which says that $16$ is a maximal value.

Comment: Nice!......[+1]

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the first derivate of $f(x)$ which is:
$$f'(x)=x\left (\frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\frac{13x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right )+9\sqrt{x^2+1}+13\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Now you have to study $f'(x)=0$ and so:
$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$
There is another solutions, bit with this we find the local maximum. Now to find the maximim, we compute:
$$f\left (\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)=16$$